# How to make a temporary variable act as * in a select statement, in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, ssms, declare

When writing a select statement with '*' (for example `select *` (...)), I'd like to use the keyboard combination [shift+2] +[2], instead of [shift+8]. This is because I can find the right shift and 2 button easier on my keyboard than the left shift and 8. Though it may look arbitrary to you, for me it isn't and the question underlying is valid anyway. At least I think it is. :)

I try to accomplish what I want by `declaring a variable` with the name '@2' and I want `the dbms to interpret that as '*' and not as a 'string *'`, so as a *-command. Later I want to make this as a global variable, but for purpose of this question I ask it as whether I only want a temporary variable.

`Is it possible` to have the dbms have it interpret it as a *-command? If so, how? Possibly I need to use a `different datatype`, but which?

See beneath the piece of script, the result now and the desired result. I hope you can help.

Piece of script:

```
declare @2 nvarchar
set @2='*'

select @2 from TableAA
```

Result now:

```
(No column name)
*
*
*
etc
```

Desired result:

```
A    B    C
1    43   25
2    33   788
3    13   83
etc.
```

//It appears it can't... See the answers beneath. I did do something else to achieve something like it: I installed AutoHotkey and wrote a script that inserts a '*' when I press Left shift an Escape. Works like a charm. See that script beneath.

```
>+Esc::
Send, *
Return
```

Comment: You need Dynamic-SQL for this like: `DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'select '+ @2 + N' from TableAA)'; EXEC(@sql);`

Comment: You cannot do what you want with a regular SQL statement.  You can input a `*` as an ASCII 42 value, if that helps.

Comment: Also do not declare `nvarchar` or `varchar` without **size**

Comment: You need some keyboard remapping tool or autohotkey or similar.

Comment: at all: thanks. @arvo: yes, I figured something like that. right now I'm diving into Windows Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4, but that just don't work on my computer. If I find a program I trust, I'll add it here.

Comment: @Arvo: I installed AutoHotkey and wrote a script that inserts a '*' when I press Left shift and Escape. Works like a charm. I also added that to the original question. >+Esc:: Send, * Return –. Thanks four your suggestion. This is even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables names to bind columns. You have to use `Dynamic SQL` in following:

```
DECLARE @2 NVARCHAR(10)  
SET @2 = '*'  
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000); 

SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + @2 + ' FROM TableAA'
EXEC(@sql)
```